# Unclear crash report in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, enumeration

I found couple of strange crash issues in my app and here is the details of it

```
Incident Identifier: 9ECA0354-F69F-4562-A9FC-4904319BFC72
CrashReporter Key:   7e75d7f19d6ccbb07328f3b3317626187ecbc9bb
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:        myApp [1760]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/7E5B3CA8-81BA-4F6A-A2A8-1B8F4060A037/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:      myApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-09-24 11:33:16.513 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  11

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x342c229e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bfa697a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x342c1d80 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   Foundation                      0x34b62504 -[NSConcreteMapTable countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 52
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3424ad34 -[__NSFastEnumerationEnumerator nextObject] + 128
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3421df0c -[NSEnumerator countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 44
6   Foundation                      0x34c7208e -[NSISEngine enumerateRows:] + 210
7   Foundation                      0x34c77fda -[NSISEngine description] + 118
8   CoreFoundation                  0x34232892 -[NSObject(NSObject) _copyDescription] + 30
9   CoreFoundation                  0x342a32d6 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11134
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3423dfa4 CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArguments + 68
11  CoreFoundation                  0x342c2190 +[NSException raise:format:] + 52
12  Foundation                      0x34c7411a -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 186
13  Foundation                      0x34c76754 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 56
14  Foundation                      0x34c76e6a -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 630
15  Foundation                      0x34c7fbba -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 390
16  UIKit                           0x365033bc -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 124
17  UIKit                           0x36503530 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 32
18  UIKit                           0x360ea2dc -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 372
19  UIKit                           0x360ea5c2 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1114
20  UIKit                           0x360e4e4e -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 134
21  UIKit                           0x360cc7d8 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1296
22  UIKit                           0x360e9af2 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 66
23  UIKit                           0x360e993a -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 126
24  UIKit                           0x360fc0a0 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow:] + 1696
25  UIKit                           0x360fa506 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1810
26  UIKit                           0x361117ca -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 202
27  UIKit                           0x360cd7fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
28  QuartzCore                      0x35e77d86 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
29  QuartzCore                      0x35e77924 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
30  QuartzCore                      0x35e78858 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
31  QuartzCore                      0x35e7823e CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
32  QuartzCore                      0x35e7804c CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
33  QuartzCore                      0x35e77eac CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
34  CoreFoundation                  0x342976c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
35  CoreFoundation                  0x342959bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
36  CoreFoundation                  0x34295d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
37  CoreFoundation                  0x34208eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
38  CoreFoundation                  0x34208d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
39  GraphicsServices                0x37dd02e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
40  UIKit                           0x3611e2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
41  myApp                       0x000a4aca 0xa2000 + 10954
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x3c3ddb1c start + 0
```

It says that thread 11 is crashed but this looks like main thread crash as I can see from last line. The thread 11 stack trace looks like this

```
   Thread 11 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c4a4d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3f2cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3f2a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3f28a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Also the crash report points out that app was crashed while doing enumeration but I am not sure how it is related to UIView and UITableView objects as I see from the stack trace. Some more info, I have tableview which shows a list if data, this is fetched from server.

Can some help me in fixing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Anything on the console? Are you modifying the collection while enumerating?

Comment: Looks like a classic race condition: something is executing on thread 11, which MUST execute on the main thread.

Comment: which part of the code throws the exception?

Comment: @Eiko : I am not sure what was on the console, this report was submitted by testing team.

Comment: @holex: Not sure which part did this, but still investigating on this.

Comment: I did check my storyboard for contraints and found couple of them in the table cell were duplicate. Was this a issue for crash?

Comment: One of my beta testers just sent me similar crash. This happens, when he pressed back navigation button. So this happens when navigation controllers pops.

Answer (score 1):

@nkd, why not use a Crash Reporting Manager like , [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk/) it does a two step symbolication process, once at the app, and at the server side, to give you exact location of your crash with all thread information, testing environment etc. 
I have been using this extensively, helps a lot in resolving bugs.

Comment: I am using crittercism and it didn't log this issue, but I got this from testing team. crittercism is a good tool to identify the crash issues.